# Deleting .ICEauthority file

Tags: system, debian, matplotlib

I had some problems with matplotlib (Python). Someone had [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20621070/ice-default-io-error-handler-doing-an-exit-pid-11281-errno-4) deleting **.ICEauthority** file. I did it and my problem with Python is solved. Is that going to cause any side-effects on my system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have removed those files for about a month now. I had to do this on three different computers, and they are all working fine now. So, I suppose removing **.ICEauthority** file doesn't affect anything noticeably.

Comment: It's been about 6 month and everything is still fine.

Comment: **Update:** more than a year, an nothing happened. It must be OK then.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/714015/accidentally-deleted-iceauthority-and-xauthority-files